# Simple script to copy check and delete

Tags: copy

I am brand new to scripts and would like to be able to write a script to copy a file (example.doc) from the source `C:\Test` to destination `D:\Destination` which checks that the copy has been successful and then deletes the original file.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You should probably add some specifics to your question. What operating system are you using, what kind of script? Bash? DOS?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you :). I am using windows, was planning on using notepad and turning in into a .bat. I understand how to make them just could do with some help in how to go about writing it. I've found copy and xcopy commands which i understand however checking if a file is copied and then deleting the old one I'm still trying to learn.  Many thanks

Comment: You should [edit] the info into your question, instead of adding a comment.  Comments are fleeting, and the more information self-contained in the question itself, the better.

Answer (score 0):

A couple answers:

Research "move" (maybe, Google "batch files move"). The short documentation at the command prompt (move /?) doesn't specifically address whether it checks that the file arrived correctly before erasing the original, but it seems like a kinda obvious thing for the developers to do. There's probably someplace on the web that'll confirm whether they do that.

If that works, try "move C:\Test\example.doc D:\Destination". That'll probably do it.

Or, write a batch file, maybe mymove.bat

```
copy C:\Test\example.doc D:\Destination
if exist D:\Destination\example.doc del C:\Test\example.doc
```

You can get more elaborate: using a parameter to specify the file name, checking whether D:\Destination\example.doc and C:\Test\example.doc have the same size before you delete, using some switches to keep from getting prompted about things and similar. Maybe this'll get you started.

For all these batch file commands (move, copy, del, dir), you can get some good documentation for your particular operating system at the command prompt. Type `<cmd> /?` (like the `move /?` I mentioned above).

Batch file programming is tedious and frustrating, but it's available to all of us! Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a great help. Much appreciated